# Combination of CUDA 9 and GCC4.3 compiled C++ Software

Tags: c++, gcc, cuda

I currently need to write a project paper for my studies. My challenge will be to find some calculations in a given software, that can be put on a graphics card to speed up the whole software. 
The problem I currently have is to decide whether to use CUDA or OpenCL. 
I wanted to start checking if CUDA would be a good choice for my aims, but i cannot find any posts about the following problem:
The software I should analyze uses GCC 4.3 and c++03 standard (I know that's very old, but these are requirements by the client).

**Is it possible to take a newer CUDA version and make it work with software compiled by gcc4.3?**

I hope somebody might help me with this.

Comment: The supported compiler  matrix for CUDA 9 is here: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html

Comment: I know I need gcc 4.8 for installing CUDA but is it possible to LINK compiled CUDA Code against gcc4.3 compiled c++ code?

Comment: You are asking the wrong question. It is libC and  libC++ which define binary compatibility, not the compiler. Do you have a platform which has a supported version of CUDA and both GCC 4.3 and a supported host compiler built on the sale ABI/libC versions?

Comment: Well, I see your point but I have no idea how to look up, which libc both compilers are using.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I tested linking of nvcc 9 compiled cuda kernel against gcc4.3 compiled C++ code and it worked fine.